# Why the Neural Network started to perform worse after I scaled the dataset using MinMax?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-scaling

Data I was trying to classify using NN (it was generated using sklearns'[`make_blobs`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html) method):

[image]

The model I used

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,input_shape=(2,),activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',)

history = model.fit(X,y,epochs=100,verbose=0)
```

The results (f1 score) after training neural network 100 times on the unscaled and scaled (MinMax) dataset

[image]

[image]

**Why network's performance worsened after I scaled dataset?** I'd thought that scaling data would result in a better performance, not a *worse* one.

Comment: When you scaled the data, did you also tune the learning rate? Different scales imply different learning rates.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica  No, I didn't. The default one was used, `0.001`.  And yes, f1 score increased after I tuned it like you suggested (increased to `0.01`). Thanks!

Comment: Are you reporting train,validation or testset accuracy? If it is train, probably you are just seeing different degrees of overfitting...